# BASH : got to the upper imbricated case

Tags: bash, menu, case

It is my first question, so I hope that I'm clear enough
I have the following problem with a case inside a case. 
the first one is a menu which trigger a function. inside the function there a an other case. In case user select NO, he should come back to the first case. 
I have not found how to do that beside of launching the first script ( containing the first case:

`menu.sh`:

```
source ./functions.sh

#read answer

while read answer;do

    case $answer in

    1)
        function1
    ;;

    2)
        function2
    ;;
    3)
       # the same, without function 
       read -p "do you want to continue [y/n] ?" choice

       case $choice in
       y|Y)
            # DO SOME STUFF
            menu.sh
       ;;   
       n|N )
            ./menu.sh 
       ;;
       *) 
            echo "invalid input"
           ./menu.sh
       ;;
       esac

    4)
        function4
    ;;

    5)
        quit
    ;;
    esac
done
```

`functions.sh`:

```
function1() {

read -p "do you want to continue [y/n] ?" choice

       case $choice in
       y|Y)
            # DO SOME STUFF and go back to menu
            echo "hello"
            menu.sh
       ;;   
       n|N )
            ./menu.sh 
       ;;
       *) 
            echo "invalid input"
           ./menu.sh
       ;;
       esac


}
```

so as you can see, when the function is launched, it launched the second case where the user is asked if he wants to continue. If he choose no, he can go back the menu. But with the way i m doing, i m spawning a menu.sh inside the case. 
What is the better solution?
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Use a function or loop instead of calling the script again. Or just let the second script end and you will return to the first, you don't need to call it again. Intead of `./menu.sh`, just do `exit`.

Comment: FYI: You are missing a `;;` before `4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your code layed out, you don't need to run anything to go back to the menu. Just delete the lines in which you are spawning the **menu.sh**.

An example `function1` would look like:

```
function1() {
read -p "do you want to continue [y/n] ?" choice
       case $choice in
       y|Y)
            # DO SOME STUFF and go back to menu
            echo "hello"
       ;;   
       n|N )

       ;;
       *) 
            echo "invalid input"
       ;;
       esac
}
```

And change

```
while read answer;do
```

To

```
while read -p "Enter a number: " answer;do
```

It will make it easier to understand how things are working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Was a little problem of loggic from my side